# Laravel vendor:publish

Tags: laravel, artisan, publish

Ahora que ya me he enterado de lo que hace el comando de artisan `vendor:publish`, me gustaría encontrar alguna referencia de posibles paquetes a publicar y como especificarlos. He visto aquí y allí algunos usos con la opción `--tag`, y también con la opción `--provider`, pero no sé cuando usar una u otra, ni que hay que poner en la opción elegida para publicar lo que yo deseo en cada caso, ni en que directorios se publica ese material. Por ejemplo, si yo deseo publicar las funciones de autenticación, ¿qué pondría en la opción `--tag`? Y si deseo publicar los correos de restablecer contraseña, y confirmar email, y traducirlos a otros idiomas, ¿cómo lo haría?. He buscado en Internet, y no encuentro una referencia exhaustiva de estas opciones. Si alguien sabe donde encontrarla, por favor, decírmelo.

Comment: Trata de enfocar mejor tu pregunta para que quien te ayude pueda hacerlo de forma mas efectiva, tu pregunta al momento es muy amplia pues incluye varias dudas y puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Sí, quizá no soy buena redactando, pero las preguntas que se incluyen son distintos aspectos de la misma duda. Busco documentación detallada y exhaustiva sobre las opciones de vendor publish, pero si sólo pongo eso, quedaría muy escueto, y sería difícil saber a que me refiero. No sé como enfocarla de otra forma. No me la cerréis, por favor, que lo mismo la lee alguien que sepa donde buscar.

Comment: ¿Ya leiste [esto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages)?